# Can not update or install package ubuntu

Tags: 12.04

While trying to install any update from update manager or Terminal OR install package from software center or Terminal I get this error. Can any one help me to solve this problem. I have tried moving .dat file to another destination. Even copied .onfig file to mode-available. But can not solve this problem.

```
root@krutarth-Vostro-270s:/home/krutarth# apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gir1.2-ubuntuoneui-3.0 libbsd0 linux-headers-3.5.0-23-generic
  linux-headers-3.5.0-23 libubuntuoneui-3.0-1
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libapache2-mod-php5 php5-cli php5-common php5-curl php5-gd php5-imap
  php5-intl php5-mcrypt php5-mysql php5-pspell php5-readline php5-recode
  php5-snmp php5-sqlite php5-tidy php5-xmlrpc php5-xsl
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libapache2-mod-php5 php5-cli php5-common php5-curl php5-gd php5-imap
  php5-intl php5-mcrypt php5-mysql php5-pspell php5-readline php5-recode
  php5-snmp php5-sqlite php5-tidy php5-xmlrpc php5-xsl
17 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 60 not upgraded.
17 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/6,003 kB of archives.
After this operation, 4,096 B disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
Setting up php5-common (5.4.33-2+deb.sury.org~precise+1) ...
ERROR: pdo module symlink already exists in /etc/php5/conf.d with different content
dpkg: error processing php5-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libapache2-mod-php5:
 libapache2-mod-php5 depends on php5-common (= 5.4.33-2+deb.sury.org~precise+1); however:
  Package php5-common is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libapache2-mod-php5 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php5-cli:
 php5-cli depends on php5-common (= 5.4.33-2+deb.sury.org~precise+1); however:
  Package php5-common is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing php5-cli (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php5-readline:
 php5-readline depends on phpapi-20100525; however:
  Package phpapi-20100525 is not installed.
  Package libapache2-mod-php5 which provides phpapi-20100525 is not configured yet.
  Package php5-cli which provides phpapi-20100525 is not configured yet.
 php5-readline depends on php5-common (= 5.4.32-2+deb.sury.org~precise+1); however:
  Version of php5-coNo apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                              No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                        No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                      No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                    No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                  No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                            No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                          No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
        No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                      No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                    No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                  No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                mmon on system is 5.4.33-2+deb.sury.org~precise+1.
 php5-readline depends on php5-cli (= 5.4.32-2+deb.sury.org~precise+1); however:
  Version of php5-cli on system is 5.4.33-2+deb.sury.org~precise+1.
dpkg: error processing php5-readline (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php5-intl:
 php5-intl depends on phpapi-20100525; however:
  Package phpapi-20100525 is not installed.
  Package libapache2-mod-php5 which provides phpapi-20100525 is not configured yet.
  Package php5-cli which provides phpapi-20100525 is not configured yet.
 php5-intl depends on php5-common (= 5.4.32-2+deb.sury.org~precise+1); however:
  Version of php5-common on system is 5.4.33-2+deb.sury.org~precise+1.
dpkg: error processing php5-intl (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php5-mysql:
 php5-mysql depends on phpapi-20100525; however:
  Package phpapi-20100525 is not installed.
 No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                               No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                              Package libapache2-mod-php5 which provides phpapi-20100525 is not configured yet.
  Package php5-cli which provides phpapi-20100525 is not configured yet.
 php5-mysql depends on php5-common (= 5.4.32-2+deb.sury.org~precise+1); however:
  Version of php5-common on system is 5.4.33-2+deb.sury.org~precise+1.
dpkg: error processing php5-mysql (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php5-imap:
 php5-imap depends on phpapi-20100525; however:
  Package phpapi-20100525 is not installed.
  Package libapache2-mod-php5 which provides phpapi-20100525 is not configured yet.
  Package php5-cli which provides phpapi-20100525 is not configured yet.
 php5-imap depends on php5-common (= 5.4.32-2+deb.sury.org~precise+1); however:
  Version of php5-common on system is 5.4.33-2+deb.sury.org~precise+1.
dpkg: error processing php5-imap (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php5-xsl:
 php5-xsl depends on phpapi-20100525; however:
  Package phpapi-20100525 is not installed.
  Package libapache2-mod-php5 which provides phpapi-20100525 is not configured yet.
  Package php5-cli which provides phpapi-20100525 is not configured yet.
 php5-xsl depends on php5-common (= 5.4.32-2+deb.sury.org~precise+1); however:
  Version of php5-common on system is 5.4.33-2+deb.sury.org~precise+1.
dpkg: error processing php5-xsl (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php5-mcrypt:
 php5-mcrypt depends on phpapi-20100525; however:
  Package phpapi-20100525 is not installed.
  Package libapache2-mod-php5 which provides phpapi-20100525 is not configured yet.
  Package php5-cli which provides phpapi-20100525 is not configured yet.
 php5-mcrypt depends on php5-common (= 5.4.32-2+deb.sury.org~precise+1); however:
  Version of php5-common on system is 5.4.33-2+deb.sury.org~precise+1.
dpkg: error processing php5-mcrypt (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php5-pspell:
 php5-pspell depends on phpapi-20100525; however:
  Package phpapi-20100525 is not installed.
  Package libapache2-mod-php5 which provides phpapi-20100525 is not configured yet.
  Package php5-cli which provides phpapi-20100525 is not configured yet.
 php5-pspell depends on php5-common (= 5.4.32-2+deb.sury.org~precise+1); however:
  Version of php5-common on system is 5.4.33-2+deb.sury.org~precise+1.
dpkg: error processing php5-pspell (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php5-snmp:
 php5-snmp depends on phpapi-20100525; however:
  Package phpapi-20100525 is not installed.
  Package libapache2-mod-php5 which provides phpapi-20100525 is not configured yet.
  Package php5-cli which provides phpapi-20100525 is not configured yet.
 php5-snmp depends on php5-common (= 5.4.32-2+deb.sury.org~precise+1); however:
  Version of php5-common on system is 5.4.33-2+deb.sury.org~precise+1.
dpkg: error processing php5-snmp (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php5-curl:
 php5-curl depends on phpapi-20100525; however:
  Package phpapi-20100525 is not installed.
  Package libapache2-mod-php5 which provides phpapi-20100525 is not configured yet.
  Package php5-cli which provides phpapi-20100525 is not configured yet.
 php5-curl depends on php5-common (= 5.4.32-2+deb.sury.org~precise+1); however:
  Version of php5-common on system is 5.4.33-2+deb.sury.org~precise+1.
dpkg: error processing php5-curl (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php5-recode:
 php5-recode depends on phpapi-20100525; however:
  Package phpapi-20100525 is not installed.
  Package libapache2-mod-php5 which provides phpapi-20100525 is not configured yet.
  Package php5-cli which provides phpapi-20100525 is not configured yet.
 php5-recode depends on php5-common (= 5.4.32-2+deb.sury.org~precise+1); however:
  Version of php5-common on system is 5.4.33-2+deb.sury.org~precise+1.
dpkg: error processing php5-recode (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php5-xmlrpc:
 php5-xmlrpc depends on phpapi-20100525; however:
  Package phpapi-20100525 is not installed.
  Package libapache2-mod-php5 which provides phpapi-20100525 is not configured yet.
  Package php5-cli which provides phpapi-20100525 is not configured yet.
 php5-xmlrpc depends on php5-common (= 5.4.32-2+deb.sury.org~precise+1); however:
  Version of php5-common on system is 5.4.33-2+deb.sury.org~precise+1.
dpkg: error processing php5-xmlrpc (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php5-sqlite:
 php5-sqlite depends on phpapi-20100525; however:
  Package phpapi-20100525 is not installed.
  Package libapache2-mod-php5 which provides phpapi-20100525 is not configured yet.
  Package php5-cli which provides phpapi-20100525 is not configured yet.
 php5-sqlite depends on php5-common (= 5.4.32-2+deb.sury.org~precise+1); however:
  Version of php5-common on system is 5.4.33-2+deb.sury.org~precise+1.
dpkg: error processing php5-sqlite (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php5-gd:
 php5-gd depends on phpapi-20100525; however:
  Package phpapi-20100525 is not installed.
  Package libapache2-mod-php5 which provides phpapi-20100525 is not configured yet.
  Package php5-cli which provides phpapi-20100525 is not configured yet.
 php5-gd depends on php5-common (= 5.4.32-2+deb.sury.org~precise+1); however:
  Version of php5-common on system is 5.4.33-2+deb.sury.org~precise+1.
dpkg: error processing php5-gd (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php5-tidy:
 php5-tidy depends on phpapi-20100525; however:
  Package phpapi-20100525 is not installed.
  Package libapache2-mod-php5 which provides phpapi-20100525 is not configured yet.
  Package php5-cli which provides phpapi-20100525 is not configured yet.
 php5-tidy depends on php5-common (= 5.4.32-2+deb.sury.org~precise+1); however:
  Version of php5-common on system is 5.4.33-2+deb.sury.org~precise+1.
dpkg: error processing php5-tidy (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 php5-common
 libapache2-mod-php5
 php5-cli
 php5-readline
 php5-intl
 php5-mysql
 php5-imap
 php5-xsl
 php5-mcrypt
 php5-pspell
 php5-snmp
 php5-curl
 php5-recode
 php5-xmlrpc
 php5-sqlite
 php5-gd
 php5-tidy
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 1st problem starts with php5-common and a pdo module:

```
Setting up php5-common (5.4.33-2+deb.sury.org~precise+1) ...
ERROR: pdo module symlink already exists in /etc/php5/conf.d with different content
```

So I would suggest to remove the pdo file and re-install php5-common 1st.

- Backup `/var/lib/dpkg/status` just to be sure with something like `cp /var/lib/dpkg/status /var/lib/dpkg/status.backup`
- Delete all entries to `php5-common` in `/var/lib/dpkg/status` with a text editor like nano or vi.
- Backup and remove the current `pdo` with `sudo mv /etc/php5/conf.d/10-pdo.ini /etc/php5/conf.d/10-pdo.ini.backup`

After that `apt-get install php5-common` installation should install `php5-common` and then you should be able to use `apt-get -f install` without problems.

Comment: Your solution worked for me, but Now I am getting this error from apache : `apache2: Syntax error on line 210 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so into server: libqdbm.so.14: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Action 'configtest' failed.`